# how to construct SOLR query and schema that matches keywords and sorts by external keyword ranking

Tags: solr

Hope someone can help guide me in the right direction on this SOLR question...

I have a dataset that includes hotel features and ratings.  Examples of features are 'pool', 'gym', 'free wifi'.  Each feature has a rating between 1 and 10.  I would like to use SOLR to query these feature/rating pairs in conjunction with some other hotel-related criteria like 'hotel name' or 'location' so that the hotels with most matching and highest rated features go to the top of the search results.  Here's an example:

Imagine an end user is searching for a hotel in New York City (location:"New York City) that as 'free wifi' and a 'pool'.  Ideally, the matches at the top of the search results are hotels in NYC that have 'free wifi' and 'pool' with the highest ratings.  Hope that makes sense?  Can anyone send me in the direction of the SOLR features that will allow be to execute this type of query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the edismax handler and do this in two parts.

First, does the hotel have a pool? Either use a field with multiple values, so you can search for amenities:pool, amenities:gym, etc., or use a set of boolean fields, pool:True, gym:True.

Second, have a field for the ratings, and use the boost feature to boost by each rating. The score will be multiplied by the boost. I've used a max() to make sure that a zero or negative rating does not cause problems. Here is a sample definition that would go into the request handler config in solrconfig.xml:

```
<str name="boost">product(max(pool_rating,1),max(gym_rating,1))</str>
```

product() accepts multiple args, so you can just keep adding them.

Comment: Thanks Walter.  I am not completely sure I understand fully, but let me research what you say in your answer and give it a try!

Comment: Hi Walter.  I read through the SOLR docs et al (I am a SOLR newbie ;-) and now understand what you are suggesting.  I have a follow up question: if the list of amenities got to be very long, would you change the approach?  My concern is any potential performance bottlenecks with having something like <str name="boost">product(a_rating, b_rating, ... zzzz_rating)</str> running in SOLR.  There are several hundred unique amenities and a total search data set of many hundreds of thousands of hotels.  Thanks in advance for any advice!